# Path to sdcard, incompatible types

Tags: android, path

I use:

```
Path mypath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myfile/asong.mp3";
```

But that gives incompatible types, found String and required Path. How can I set a path to this particular path of sdcard? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

see this example:

This is what I am using:

Activity..
createDirIfNotExists("/data/XXXX/XXXX/XXX");

```
public static boolean createDirIfNotExists(String path) {
    boolean ret = true;
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+path);
    Debug.out(path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Debug.out("Problem creating Image folder");
            ret = false;
        }
    }
    if (FolderLocation == null)
        FolderLocation = new File(file.toString());
    return ret; 
}
```

....
....
for example I want to record a sound to a file:

```
            File outputFile = new File(FolderLocation, filename+".3gp");
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(outputFile.toString());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
                Debug.out("button_play.setOnClickListener ERROR");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Path class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) is not some path of a file. It represents paths in drawings in canvas. To store path of a file, you can store it in a String, Uri or in a File object.